# apacite+bibtopic: how not to print heading

Tags: apa-style

I need to give multiple bibliography list in tex file in APA style.

Here's an example code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, draft]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{bibtopic}

\begin{document}

\chapter{FIRST CHAPTER}

\begin{btSect}[apacite]{bibfile}
    \section{First citation list}
    \btPrintAll
\end{btSect}
\end{document}
```

If I'm using `plain` style, there's no "References" above the citation list (default behavior of `bibtopic`). But using `apacite` style the "Reference" cannot be avoided.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\usepackage[notocbib]{apacite}
```

Afterwards you could change the bibname by using:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bla}
```

Perhaps you also want to add the bibname back to the table of contents. You can do so using

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
```